# Request.IsAuthenticated is never true

Tags: asp.net, authentication, httprequest, httpmodule, httpcontext

I've got an `HttpModule` implemented that's supposed to restrict access to the `/courses/` directory of my site, but there's one major problem with it.

`Request.IsAuthenticated` is always `false`.

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public class CourseAuthenticationModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose() { }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(BeginRequest);
    }

    public void BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)source;
        HttpContext context = app.Context;
        HttpRequest request = context.Request;
        HttpResponse response = context.Response;

        if (request.Path.ToLower().StartsWith("/courses/") 
            && !request.IsAuthenticated)

        {
            response.Redirect("/");
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea why this happens, but the condition will *always* evaluate to `true` when accessing the `/courses/` directory.

**Edit:**

I found this in the Web.Config. Not sure if it's relevant.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="userlogin.asp" name=".cc" protection="All" path="/" timeout="2880" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using? Can you show us that code?

Comment: @kehrk Try to attach also with `IIdentity` to see if works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The BeginRequest as the first event is too early to ask if the user is authenticated or not.

At that point you can simple check if its authenticated by direct read the cookie as:

```
string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;    
HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[cookieName];

if (null == authCookie || FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value) == null)
{
    // is not authenticated
}
```

Comment: `FormsAuthentication.Decrypt()` takes a string, not an `HttpCookie`: `The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(string)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: @kehrk Sorry, for this, use the string of the cookie, I type it from memory and make this mistake. I have update the answer, but also check the IIdentity to add it to your class, it may be direct work.

Comment: No worries. I think this *almost* works, but I'll have to pick it up again tomorrow. Thanks a ton for your help!

Comment: Aristos is right about BeginRequest being too early. You would need to inspect it in  Application_AuthenticateRequest event. 

However, that's not enough.

In order for the request.IsAuthenticated to evaluate to true, you would need to set the Request.Identity object via code or built in Membership Services  to an object that supports the IsAuthenicated iface member.